# What Makes Oils Feel Dry or Oily?

Tags: lipids

Simple question with a complex answer, certainly:

Why do some oils feel "dry," while others feel "oily"? Is the feel directly related to C-chain length, or hydrogenation, active groups, or something else entirely?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Best of luck!

Comment: I didn't know they did. Can you give examples?

Comment: What do you mean by oil? It is a quite broad definition and in a perhaps slang  includes everything insoluble in water for which a solid is not (yet?) attained after synthesis.